# Inserting complex count() query results to table

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

- Note: This question was previously oversimplified; the question has been appended to give a better understanding of my problem

I have table of shipment data of a company, called t_shipment. (Some of) the headers are acc_num, type_of_business, contract_exception, payment_status, etc.

I need to make a recap table for the other dept.'s side of work. So I make a new table, ship_recap, using CREATE TABLE.

```
CREATE TABLE ship_recap
(vol_lumber(int), vol_oil(int);)
```

Then I need to recap the relevant data from t_shipment to the ship_recap. I used

```
 INSERT INTO ship_recap (vol_lumber)
 SELECT COUNT(acc_num) from t_shipment WHERE type_of_business = 'LMB' and (contract_exception = 'VALID' OR payment_status IS NOT NULL)
 INSERT INTO ship_recap (vol_oil)
 SELECT COUNT(acc_num) from t_shipment where type_of_business = 'OIL' and (contract_exception = 'VALID' OR payment_status IS NOT NULL);)
```

It ran, but the result was:

```
 ____________________
|vol_lumber| vol_oil |
----------------------
|   150    |   NULL  |
|   NULL   |   230   |
----------------------
```

But instead I want them to be:

```
 ____________________
|vol_lumber| vol_oil |
----------------------
|   150    |   230   |
----------------------
```

I tried using

```
INSERT INTO ship_recap (vol_lumber, vol_oil)
(SELECT COUNT(acc_num) from t_shipment WHERE type_of_business = 'LMB' and (contract_exception = 'VALID' OR payment_status IS NOT NULL),
SELECT COUNT(acc_num) from t_shipment where type_of_business = 'OIL' and (contract_exception = 'VALID' OR payment_status IS NOT NULL);)
```

And permutations of the same logic (e.g. changing the comma into a semicolon, or taking out the parentheses), but it returned a syntax error every time.

The results/recap table might have as many as 20+ headers and other queries might get slightly more complicated too.
I need a way to correctly insert the SELECT/COUNT-ed data to the recap table and keep them in one row.

EDIT: As per Reno's suggestion, I tried this

```
 CREATE TABLE ship_recap (vol_OIL int,vol_LUM int,vol_BEV int,processed_OIL int,processed_LUM int,processed_BEV int);
 INSERT INTO ship_recap (vol_OIL, vol_LUM, vol_BEV, processed_OIL, processed_LUM, processed_BEV)
 SELECT
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'OIL' and process_date = '2016-05-12', 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'LUM' and process_date = '2016-05-12', 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'BEV' and process_date = '2016-05-12', 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'OIL' and process_date = '2016-05-12' and (contract_exception = ‘VALID’ OR payment_status IS NOT NULL), 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'LUM' and process_date = '2016-05-12' and (contract_exception = ‘VALID’ OR payment_status IS NOT NULL), 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'BEV' and process_date = '2016-05-12' and (contract_exception = ‘VALID’ OR payment_status IS NOT NULL), 1, NULL)) FROM t_shipment;
```

It worked once I corrected the missing parameters and parentheses.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(fruit = 'apple') apple, SUM(fruit = 'banana') banana FROM my_table;` I have no idea why you would store this derived data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following sql, may help for you;)

```
 CREATE TABLE ship_recap (vol_OIL int,vol_LUM int,vol_BEV int,processed_OIL int,processed_LUM int,processed_BEV int);
 INSERT INTO ship_recap (vol_OIL, vol_LUM, vol_BEV, processed_OIL, processed_LUM, processed_BEV)
 SELECT
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'OIL' and process_date = '2016-05-12', 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'LUM' and process_date = '2016-05-12', 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'BEV' and process_date = '2016-05-12', 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'OIL' and process_date = '2016-05-12' and (contract_exception = ‘VALID’ OR payment_status IS NOT NULL), 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'LUM' and process_date = '2016-05-12' and (contract_exception = ‘VALID’ OR payment_status IS NOT NULL), 1, NULL)),
  COUNT(IF(type_of_business = 'BEV' and process_date = '2016-05-12' and (contract_exception = ‘VALID’ OR payment_status IS NOT NULL), 1, NULL)) FROM t_shipment;
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually the query is longer than that (my bad for oversimplifying it.)

`e.g.:INSERT INTO top_shipper (vol_lumber, vol_oil)`
`SELECT count(acc_num) from ship_main where type_of_business = 'LMB' and (contract_exception = 'VALID' OR payment_status IS NOT NULL),`
`select count(acc_num) from where type_of_busines = 'OIL' and (contract_exception = 'VALID' OR payment_status IS NOT NULL);)`

The results/recap table might have as many as 25 headers and each query might be slightly more complicated too.

Comment: @Rheine So why don't you edit your post again, let us be more clear to your question please.:D

Comment: Edited, please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Rheine I've updated `insert` sql, check it again please.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it still returned a syntax error. My question is updated with the exact query I used.

Comment: You missed `,1,null` in last `count` expression and `)` in other, try my sql pls.

Comment: Corrected it, but still didn't work. The error message was:
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(IF(business_type = 'OIL', and process_date = '2016-05-12',1,NULL),' at line 3

Comment: Yes, not just `,1,null` error, check my sql. You also missed a `)` in first three `count` expression.

Comment: It worked like magic. Thank you. :)
Before I close it, what is the '1, Null' part for? Just for better understanding.

Comment: `count(1)` is as same as `count(*)` or `count(column)`, and if column's value is null, `count` will skip this record.